# How to load a url in html div and post data through http post method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http

I have written a html page, and I wrote following code where I am using Jquery to load a specific url inside a html div :

```
<html>

<head>
<title>forms</title>

<%
String outputLink = ServerSupportUtil.getAttributeStringValue(request,"outputlink");
String secParam = ServerSupportUtil.getAttributeStringValue(request,"secparam");
%>

<script src="../common/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#menu").html('<object data="<%=outputlink%>">').appendTo('body');;
   });

</script> 

</head>

<body>

<div id="menu" style="position:relative; bottom: 0; overflow:hidden;">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Above code is working good.

Now I also want to send a specific parameter named as **secParam**(which I get from request object) through http post along with this url so that server can do authentication.

So how should I load the same url in the div by doing http post request? 
Is this possible using Jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

First create an simple container to display whats retuned. Then use jquery $.post() method :

```
//Empty container div
<div id="container"></div>

$.post('ajax/test.html', { secParam: "<%=secParam%>" }, function(data) {
  $('#container').html(data);
});
```

I would recommend you not to use jsp scriptlets if that's what i see here.

Comment: I want to call this url along with http post request. If I will not send any data through post, then server will not authenticate user.

Comment: do you mean you want to hit 2 post url's in one click?

Answer (score 0):

String outputLink = ServerSupportUtil.getAttributeStringValue(request,"outputlink");
You have used a request method to request data(page) from server, so if you want to post the parameter to server used post method,you should change request to post, maybe cannot use the code above, you should create a html form and save your parameter in a hidden, and set the form action as the outputlink you request, you can get the parameter from the httpRequest.